# How to connect vertica with apache superset?

Tags: python, vertica, apache-superset

I am trying to connect vertica with apache superset in

superset --> add database --> SQLAlchemy URI : vertica+vertica_python://dbadmin:password@localhost:5433/test

I am running apache superset in docker and vertica in localhost.

I check logs of docker image of superset, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/superset/superset/views/core.py", line 1759, in testconn
    engine = create_engine(uri, **engine_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 419, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 56, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 150, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 201, in load
    return self.impls[name]()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2433, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2456, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, 
extras=self.extras)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 794, in resolve
    new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2735, in requires
    "%s has no such extra feature %r" % (self, ext)
pkg_resources.UnknownExtra: vertica-python 0.9.2 has no such extra 
feature 'namedparams'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install sqlalchemy-vertica
```

instead of

```
pip install sqlalchemy-vertica-python
```